# unity 5: Flip a gameobject in a certain order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am able to flip the gameobject but my problem is that it flips before the attack animation starts. I don't know how to put this in order. Hoping someone can help.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(4f, 0);       
        StartCoroutine(enemyReturn());
    }
}

IEnumerator enemyReturn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.1f);
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("slimeMelee"); //attack animation
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale; theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One trivial solution would be to yield some time before fliping:

```
IEnumerator enemyReturn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.1f);
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("slimeMelee"); //attack animation
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); // Setup this yield time.
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale; theScale.x *= -1; transform.localScale = theScale; // code to flip
}
```

In this example, the code will yield 0.5 seconds before make the flip. You should change `0.5` with the time it fits the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the help